# How is 何者にもなれない translated?

Tags: grammar, meaning, song-lyrics

> 何者にもなれない

Let's break it down...

*何も here means nothing (with negatives)

*者 means people

*に is the target particle

*なる means to become

*なれない is the negative potential of なる

How in the world does this translate as "Unable to accomplish anything?". Does it lack context or something?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

So, someone translated:

> 「何者{なにもの}にもなれない」

into:

> "Unable to accomplish anything"

That is indeed an ***excellent*** translation in that it conveys perfectly the  meaning/essence of the original.  It is not a word-for-word translation, of course, but a word-for-word translation often makes little sense between Japanese and English.

In case you wanted a literal translation, it would be something like "***to be unable to (even) become anyone***".  IMHO, that would be far more ambiguous than "***unable to accomplish anything***".  You may, of course, disagree.

「何者」, in ***this*** context with the negative 「なれない」, means "***a worthwhile person***", "***someone who has achieved something***", "***a person worth mentioning***", etc.

「も」 means "even".

「～～になれない」 means "to be unable to become ~~".

Thus, the phrase is saying that **someone is (being) unable to become (even a bit of) a worthwhile person**.  If I am not mistaken, "to become a someone" even in English would mean "to become a worthwhile person", does it not?  We are talking "becoming successful" and "not becoming successful" here.

Do you still feel that "***unable to accomplish anything***" is a strange translation?  Quite a few users here seem to let the translated words get in their way of understanding the original.  I know that for sure because I do answer quite a few questions here.

Translation is an art, not a natural science.  The components used in one language do not have to physically correspond to those used in the other.  If the essence of the phrase/sentence is maintained and the product (= translation) sounds natural in the target language, you basically have a good translation.

Comment: 「も」 definitely doesn't mean "even" here. It's the same particle as in 「誰にも」「どこにも」 that changes the word's meaning from "who" to "nobody/anybody" or from "where" to "nowhere/anywhere". 「何者」 roughly means "who", so 「何者にも」 means "(become) anybody". The whole sentence literally means "who can't become anybody".

Comment: “Unable to accomplish anything” may not be a _strange_ translation as such, but I wouldn’t call it an excellent one either. Accomplishing something and becoming someone are two different things. You can accomplish a lot of things and still not ‘be someone’; and you can ‘be someone’ without accomplishing anything much at all. Nikolai’s suggestion of “… who will never amount to anything” is a much better translation.

Answer (score 2):

> *何も here means nothing (with negatives)
>
> *者 means people

You confused the order. 何者 means "who/what kind of person", add にも to that and you get "[become] no one" (with negatives).

A literal translation would be "who can't become anyone", where "anyone" implicitly denotes someone of importance. I agree that translation is somewhat liberal: becoming someone of importance is indeed an accomplishment, but not necessarily the other way around.

I think I've seen a different translation "who will never amount to anything" which I think fits much better.